# How to add assertions for each input when doing data driven testing

Tags: soapui

New to SoapUI. I am using SoapUI Pro data source to import data from excel.It is working fine, getting 200 for each input.What I need is For each input I have to check response data through assertions like script assertion.I am wondering how to add unique assertions for each input/row of data from excel.

I know how to do if I give the expected value also in Excel But I need to add a unique assertion for each row of data without specifying expected value in excel.

Wondering if anyone used this approach.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it something similar to [this](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-NG/Xpath-Match-Configuration/m-p/119083#M27511) you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

store the excel reference value in the context variable

how to do that?

have a groovyscript step to store the value in the context

```
context.excelvaltobeasserted = rightClickhere-->getData-->pointto the name of excel refrence
```

add the groovy script assertion

```
assert context.excelvaltobeasserted == rightClickhere-->getData-->pointTotheResponseXpath tree
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Suman.I do not have expected output in my excel.My excel has only the request elements and for each input, i need a unique assertion like when excel picks up the 2nd row, i need a different assertion to validate that.

Comment: could you please tell me what eacch row related assert does in your case?  what you want to validate ?  Using groovy script assertion you can user  switch case statements , where as this case value you need to get from excel like Row reference then write your cases. i dont think this is a best approach. i am assuming in one case you want to validate headers, in another case you want to validate fault, another case you want to validate response value , if it so this can be done groovy switch cases but this is not fruitful.

Comment: Thanks suman. To be clear.I have 3 request elements in my excel( say employer,division and product).For each row of data I need to validate the assertions.Like for first row of data, I need to see if some element in the response for the data given has a particular value and for 2nd row, I need to validate to see if another element has a particular value and so on..

Comment: Easiest way is I can add 1 sheet per 1 test step and can validate that way but i don't want to use that approach.

Comment: So it means all the rows drives the same request , at any given time only one row will be fired.. hence you need to write script assertion .. if the response content value is XXXX  then assert XXXX or if the response content value is YYY then assert YYY,  you can use groovy ifelse or switch statements , to get the response content if its json or xml, can find it here  https://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/validating-messages/using-script-assertions.html   and  for json http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37412281/script-assertion-to-get-token-and-set-it-as-http-header-to-the-next-test-step