# Script Assertion to get token and set it as http header to the next test step

Tags: json, groovy, soapui

How to write a script(assertion) in order to get the `randomAccessToken` as output from the given code.The code is in json format.

```json
{
  "status": "Success",
  "code": 1000,
  "message": "Random access token generated",
  "randomAccessToken": "ef12286f-3263-4c3b-949a-3a43497254e2-20162124112138-1722093936686484240"
}
```

**UPDATE** from comment:

I need the header name as "randomAccesstoken" but for the next TestStep because to run that I need this info.

Comment: Do want to save this token for using it other steps?

Comment: Actually I need to include this in next Test Step (like in header)

Comment: What is the header name you wanted to include?

Comment: I need the header name as "randomAccesstoken" but for the next TestStep because to run that I need this info

Comment: Check it out, the script does exactly what you wanted.

Comment: One more question
Can I add this "randomAccessToken" for more than one TestStep as header  and how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have grrovy script assertion and paste the below code.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper 
def jsponresponse = messageExchange.responseContent
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
jsonParsed = jsonSlurper.parseText(jsponresponse)
actualValue = jsonParsed.randomAccessToken
log.info actualValue

assert 12 < actualValue.length

//here you need to use groovy regx or string length grater than as assert i used srting length
```

Hope this helps!! dont forget to click answered.. if it didn't work provide your finding we solve.

Now the refined script assertion would do ,store the randomacesskey in to a property ,that can be used in next HTTP REQUEST headers

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper 
def jsponresponse = messageExchange.responseContent
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
jsonParsed = jsonSlurper.parseText(jsponresponse)
actualValue = jsonParsed.randomAccessToken
log.info actualValue    
assert 12 < actualValue.length
context.testCase.testSteps["requestProps"].setPropertyValue( "Tokenkey", actualValue )
```

what does it mean? the new line

```
context.testCase.testSteps["requestProps"].setPropertyValue( "Tokenkey", actualValue )
```

In order the above line to get execute , you need to add testStep properties and rename it as "requestProps" and add a entry "Tokenkey"

by the time the script assertion excuted successfully , script have extracted and stored randomAccessToken value in to Tokenkey refernce , for cross reference  open properties step after the execution of first request successfully and you see a value that got extracted from randomAccessToken 
i.e., you see this after executing the firt request,

```
requestProps
Tokenkey = yettqutt-ajsfugau-uyatwdua
```

Now in the another any request of the same test case which requires this extracted Randomaccess token in header section ?
How to do that ?

open that httpRequest -->headers--> add an entry that server accepts

if in your case server accepts name of the randomaccess key is "access-key"

then an add entry

```
access-key = ${requestProps#Tokenkey}
```

now fire the second or 3rd nth request you have set this header parameter in the request it will go through.

Comment: I am getting error like

startup failed: Script2.groovy: 2: unable to resolve class JsonSlurper @ line 2, column 19. def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()

Comment: added import statement now, try.. I dont have soapui installed but happy to help you

Comment: I think it's not the correct import statement 
startup failed: Script6.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class groovy.json.jsonSlurper @ line 1, column 1. import groovy.json.jsonSlurper

Comment: Yes i have added correct one now, please try it will worknow  by default assert will fail  becuase i have used 12 > bigvalue

Comment: Dont forget to click answered.. Thanks

Comment: Thank you,
Also do you know how to add "randomAccessToken" for the next Test Step in header

Comment: Glad this has helped you .. please click answered. yes you need to store this value in to a property and use that property reference in header it will work

Comment: I didn't get you "How to add this randomAccessToken for next TestStep in header".Also can you tell how to make it answered because I am new to Stackoverflow :P

Comment: [How to accept answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)?

Comment: I appriciate Mr Rao expert SOAPUI

Comment: you can either follow Roa's answer its excellent .. otherwise I am giving another answer for adding the extracted token value to the next http request

Comment: Actually Mr Rao answer doesn't add header in nest TestStep Can you give your answer

Comment: I have provided my refined answer  , in that you need to add new test step before you use refined script assertion.. check it ..

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the `script assertion`, comments in line explaining what it is doing in the each statement:

This script will fetch the value from json and set it has http header to the next test step automatically.

**UPDATE from the comment**: to add the header to next request

Make sure you have the right value for `headerName` variable, by default I have set it to `randomAccesstoken` as requested.

```groovy
import net.sf.json.groovy.JsonSlurper
//Please edit the header name you wanted
def headerName = 'randomAccesstoken'
// get the next test step name automatically, set the name if you want it for different step which is not the immediate next step
def nStepName = context.testCase.testStepList[context.currentStepIndex + 1].name


//a method which sets the headers
def setHttpHeaders(String nextStepName, def headers) {
    def nextRequest = context.testCase.testSteps[nextStepName].httpRequest
    def existingHeaders = nextRequest.requestHeaders
    headers.each {
        existingHeaders[it.key] = it.value
    }
    nextRequest.requestHeaders = existingHeaders
}


//create parser and pass the response that you received
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(messageExchange.responseContent)
//read the token
def token = json.randomAccessToken
//assert the value of token if null or empty
assert token, "Response does not contain Token or null"
//UPDATE from the comment to add the header to next request
if (token) {
  log.info "next test step name is : ${nStepName}" 
  def headerValue = [(token)]
  def headers = [(headerName) : (headerValue)]
  setHttpHeaders(nStepName, headers)
}
```

Comment: Does this code add the header for the next aTestStep

Comment: Absolutely, try it out and see. Note that `headerName` is the same you wanted and `nStepName` automatically assigns header to very next step. If you want it for other step, just provide teststep name directly instead of current dynamic assignment(based on the index of the next step).

Comment: Did you add the above as `script assertion`? Because that is what the question says. That is well tested script. Not sure what are doing. What do you see? Have you looked at the next test step header too? I am sure you missing something. Otherwise, the response could be in different format.

Comment: Yes ,Its working
But Can I add this value for more than one TestStep as header and how,because I need it in other TeseStep also

Comment: Possible, may be you consider accepting the [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) first and create a new topic for the new question with more details such as how you want token to be assigned such as for all test suites or only one test case etc which I would suggest rather keep cross posting. Or entirely there can be different solution possible in a different way, based on how you want it. Do you mind accepting it if it has helped you?

Comment: @SAICHANDRA, probably take a look at [this post](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/Adding-HTTP-headers-to-ALL-test-cases-of-a-test-suite-or-several/td-p/119545/jump-to/first-unread-message) for your new question. Hope yours looks similar.