# How to transfer dynamic TokenHeader value in all requests instead of changing the value in every request's header in SOAPUI

Tags: token, soapui

I am new in SOAP UI. I have an one scenario like I have to pass the access token value coming as a response to all the requests under the test suite.I ADD this token value in the next request header field called "TokenHeader" and it is working but my query is there any method that I can add which can be applied for all the soap requests, instead of changing the value every time for all request's header.How to automate this?Please guide me on this.

Comment: Please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37412281/script-assertion-to-get-token-and-set-it-as-http-header-to-the-next-test-step/37412910#37412910) and its comments

Comment: groovy is completely new for me, can't understand it. I will be glad if you can provide any other method for this like property transfer test step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tab header of each request and add 
**TokenHeader = ${TestStepname#Response#jsonpath}**

It will send token (received from response json) to http header of other request.